# Can black stove pipes be used for ductwork?

Tags: pipe, garage, ducts

Can I use black stove pipes for ductwork in my garage? I'm reading that I need 26 gauge duct pipes for garages, and it turns out that 24 gauge black stove pipes are a cheaper option (at least at Home Depot)!

- [24 gauge black stove pipe](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-6-in-x-24-in-Black-Stove-Pipe-BAP6X24/202191783) vs.
- [26 gauge metal duct pipe](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-6-in-x-24-in-26-Gauge-Round-Metal-Duct-Pipe-26CP6X24/100172309)

And [black stove pipe elbows](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-6-in-x-6-in-Black-Stove-Pipe-Elbow-BA90E6/202191775) are cheaper and more readily available too!

I've seen the [opposite question being asked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132548/can-i-convert-galvanized-ducts-to-wood-stove-black-ducts-by-coating-it-with-high), but haven't been able to find an answer to my question anywhere.

Comment: In some areas code is requiring insulated ductwork now I saw a notice in my jurisdiction a few weeks ago but that may be for ductwork in the crawl space and attic, not sure but you should check this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black pipe is not (usually) galvanized, since galvanization presents health risks when heated to high temps, and is therefore not suitable (and probably not legal) for HVAC ducting.

It's also usually more expensive, being of heavier gauge and painted. You should double check your pricing.

Comment: Never have seen AC ductwork that was not galvanized. Zinc boils about 1700F.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot aluminum and plastic ductwork.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was my understanding that HVAC ducts are galvanized so that they don't get rusty and leak, and it's cheaper to galvanize than paint. If these can be protected from rusting by paint (which I think is true..?), would they not work for ductwork? Also, there isn't mention of it needing to be galvanized here, maybe it's okay?  https://up.codes/viewer/washington/irc-2015/chapter/3/building-planning#R302.5.2

Thanks again!

Comment: Paint doesn't protect against rust to anywhere near the same degree as chemically bonded zinc. Also, the paint is only on the outside.

Comment: That code _wouldn't_ mention galvanization. That's not its subject.